# C# Youtube Comment Vote HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, api, youtube, httpwebrequest, comments

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.youtube.com/comment_voting?");
request.Method = "POST";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Host = "www.youtube.com";
request.Referer = "http://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=XMb63nsvQMo";
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
string postData = "a=-1&id=ElmOl_qgg14TOf2QjsVeF92YakgUMR8CTnKEbN8Rmqg&video_id=XMb63nsvQMo&old_vote=0";
byte[] postBuffer = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    postStream.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

I am working on voting comments in youtube videos. Youtube API is not supporting that voting comments so I will use webrequesting for this. I used this code to do this work but it doesn't work. No errors but nothing happens. What's wrong about my this code? You can see video id and comment id in URL.

Comment: What is the StatusCode of the response?

Comment: Can you vote without being logged in at all?